# Ionic 2 : Google Map Javascript API does not work / load on Android device

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2, geolocation

This issue has been driving me crazy for one week:

Google Maps works on a browser but not on the device, I have already removed all the `plugins` and the Android platform, then reinstalled `platform` and `plugins` but the map does not work on the device. The code :

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ionic App</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,  initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script- src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">
<!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
<script>
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
    .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
 }
</script>-->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"   rel="stylesheet">
<link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
<!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
<ion-app></ion-app>

<!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
<script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

<!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
  and contains all code in `node_modules` -->
<script src="build/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAa1urkW-Vbj-K 82Ry9jw8rPHOrXVZ_9SU"></script>
  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>
  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
   <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Any help, please !

**EDIT**

As you can see on the image bolow, the mpa load, but does not display !
[image]

**EDIT 2 :**

I have found where the issue comes from, this portion of the code works and log correctlly :

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showMap, this.showError, {  enableHightAccuracy: true })
  console.log(google);
}
```

But the "this.showMap" function does not execute.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: you tried on any other device ? which OS use on your device ?

Comment: Tried on another device with the 4.4 version it works, but in in my Android 6.0 device it doesn't work ! i olso have this error : ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object PositionError] when i run on device

Comment: I have used [angular2-google-maps](https://angular-maps.com/) npm package and was very happy with the results. Perhaps trying this other approach would get you further?

Comment: Thx, i'm trying the package, finally its a Geolocation probleme, on some device it take long time to the Geolocation to be ready...